# posterior probability of bag given ball (evidence)

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Question:**

> Given the distribution of the coloured balls in three different bags:
>   - Bag A: 1 Red 2 Black 2 Blue
>   - Bag B: 2 Red 4 Black 4 Blue
>   - Bag C: 10 Red 2 Black 3 Green
>
> we carry out two independent experiments:
>   1) pick a bag, then pick a ball from the chosen bag.
>   2) pick a ball uniformly and random from all of the 30 balls.
>
> We observe that the ball is red (for both experiment).
>   Now, we want to find *the posterior probability of ball was taken from bag C given the ball chosen is Red for each of the experiment* (i.e. P(Bag C | Red)).

**My attempt:**
*For Experiment 1:*

Using Bayes Rule we have:
P(Bag C | Red) = P(Bag C and Red) / P(Red)

```
From the distribution, we have P(BagC, Red) = 10/30
Now,P(Red)
= (by law of total probability) sum of conditional probability of
    P(Red | Bag X) * P(Bag X) 
= P(Red|BagC)*P(BagC) + P(Red|BagB)*P(BagB) + P(Red|BagA)*P(BagA)
= (1/3)(10/15) + (1/3)(2/10) + (1/3)(1/5) 
= 16/45

And hence P(BagC|Red) = (10/30) / (16/45) = 15/16 ???
```

*For Experiment 2:*

*this is the part where i am confuse, because intuitively, i dont not see the difference between both question! But i slept over it and think maybe the difference is in the way we calculate P(red), and thats why the following answer:*

So using the same formula above, but with difference calculation of the probability of getting a red ball from the bag:

```
P(Red) = total number of red / total number of balls = 13/30
Hence, P(BagC|Red) 
= P(Red, BagC) / P(Red) 
= (10/30) / (13/30) 
= 10/13
```

Intuitively, i thought my answer made sense because if we were to choose a bag first, the probability of the red ball coming from bag C will be larger since the proportion of red balls in bag C is significantly higher.

In comparison, if we pick randomly from the pool of 30 balls, the contribution of C into the pool is higher as well (10/13 red balls from C).

I am not entirely sure if my approach is correct here, and would wish that you can validate my answers.

**EDIT:**
Rectify the error pointed out in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct.  (ETA: Or was, before you edited $\frac{5}{8}$ to $\frac{15}{16}$. $<$g$>$)

Your answer to the second question is incorrect, because the $P(\text{red}, \text{Bag $C$}) = 10/30$, not $10/45$.  (That is, out of the $30$ balls, each equally likely to be selected, exactly $10$ of them are both red *and* in Bag $C$.)  You then obtain the correct answer of $10/13$.

Comment: Hi Brian, good catch. However, if thats the case, then my first answer wouldnt be correct as well, isnt it? P(red, bagC) = 10/30, then for the first experiment, we should have P(bagC | Red) = (10/30) / (16/45) = 15/16

Comment: @rockstone: No, it was right before.  You should have $P(\text{Bag $C$} \mid \text{red}) = \frac{P(\text{red}, \text{Bag $C$})}{P(\text{red})} = \frac{2/9}{16/45} = \frac{5}{8}$.  The difference is that the balls are not equally likely in the first problem; the *bags* are.

Comment: @brain, not exactly sure how you get 2/9.

Comment: @brain, after some thought, is $\frac{2}{9} = (\frac{10}{15})(\frac{1}{3}) = $ $P(red | BagC) P(C) $. Okay, then, my next question, if $P(A|B)P(B) = P(A, B)$, then for the second part, if we do use Bayes theorem, $P(BagC|red) = \frac{P(red|BagC)  P(BagC)} {P(red)} = \frac{P(red, BagC)}{P(red)}$ why do we use $\frac{10}{30}$ instead of $\frac{10}{45}$? hope you can enlighten me on this issue.

Comment: @rockstone: Because all $30$ balls are equally likely, of which $10$ are both red and in Bag $C$.

Comment: So, is it wrong to calculate $P(BagC|red) = \frac{P(red|BagC)P(BagC)}{P(red)} = \frac{(10/15)(1/3)}{13/30} = \frac{20}{39}$ for experiment two? If so, then why isnt $P(A|B)P(B) = P(A,B)$ not applicable in this case?

Comment: It is, but it's not because that rule isn't applicable in this case; it's because $P(\text{Bag $C$}) \not= \frac{1}{3}$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the pool of all $30$ balls, label the balls by the label of the bag they came from. Then, there are $10$ red 'C' balls. So the second question asks for the probability of a ball being a red 'C' ball, given that it is a red ball. There are totally $13$ red balls, and $10$ of these are 'C', so the probability is $\dfrac{10}{13}$.

You can do this using Bayes' theorem too, but you will get the same answer.

Comment: Yes, the second part should be 10/13!